# Change the Bootstrap output LESS file compiled with Grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, less

By default Grunt compiles bootstrap.less into bootstrap.css. The question is how do I make it compile my custom styles.less where I am going to import all Bootstrap less files plus some of my own into styles.css?

Comment: make a file my-theme.less (or whatever), import two files: the bootstrap.less and your styles.less -- that is the file you compile.

Comment: yes, but how do I choose an output file?

Comment: >but how do I choose an output file? - just set it in [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.1/Gruntfile.js#L161). Though it's not a good idea to modify Bootstrap package itself (obviously it may get invalidated with further BS versions), instead you'd better to create your own project with its own Grunt script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In think there are many answers for that question. I think you should following the advice of @seven-phases-max and try to not modify the source code (or at least make minimal changes).

In your `Gruntfile.js` you will find, two Less compile arguments (`compileCore` and `compileTheme`):

```
less: {
  compileCore: {
    options: {
      strictMath: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      outputSourceFiles: true,
      sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>.css.map',
      sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css.map'
    },
    src: 'less/bootstrap.less',
    dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css'
  },
  compileTheme: {
    options: {
      strictMath: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      outputSourceFiles: true,
      sourceMapURL: '<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map',
      sourceMapFilename: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css.map'
    },
    src: 'less/theme.less',
    dest: 'dist/css/<%= pkg.name %>-theme.css'
  }
}
```

And the following task defined: `grunt.registerTask('less-compile', ['less:compileCore', 'less:compileTheme']);`

It should be easy to add your own sub task and compile argument. When doing that you can compile your `styles.less` into `styles.css`. Notice that you have a separated CSS file as result. Loading that file requires a extra http request.

Unless you import bootstrap's Less code in your `styles.less` you can also not reuse Bootstrap's variables and mixins. If you need a separated CSS file consider to create your `styles.less` as follows:

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap";
//your custom code here
```

In the case that you are able to compile all you code in a single CSS file, you can do the following:

1. Create a file `custom.less` and add your customization in that file. And save that file in the same folder as your bootstrap.less file.
2. Than write at the end of the bootstrap.less file the following code: `@import "custom";`

After that you can compile bootstrap as usually.

Alternatively create custom.less as follow:

```
 @import "bootstrap";
 //your custom code here
```

To compile custom.less instead of bootstrap.less by default you should have to modify your Gruntfile.js. In the `CompileCore` argument change the src option into `src: 'less/custom.less',`.